# Rails i18: Translation missing error in yml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-5

views/ipl_mailer/confirm_doctor_form_submitted_complete.html.slim

```
p Dear #{@doctor.display_name},

p #{t('.thank_you')}
```

locales/ipl/en.yml

```
ipl: &ipl
  ipl:
    cases_review_forms:
      form: &form
        would_approve: "Approve(Yes/No)"
      edit:
        <<: *form
  ipl_mailer:
    confirm_doctor_form_submitted_complete:
      thank_you: 'Thank you for reviewing your ClinCheck treatment plans. We have received your response and noted that all plans are approved.'
```

I am getting the following error:

**I18n.t("thank_you")
"translation missing: en-US.thank_you"**

Is it because im doing it in en.yml file instead of en-US.yml

Answer (score 0):

your `I18n` is trying to find element in yml file inside `en-US`

`yml` file should be as below:

```
en:
  ipl: &ipl
    ipl_mailer:
      confirm_doctor_form_submitted_complete:
        thank_you: 'Thank you for'
```

then you can access it as below:

```
I18n.t('ipl.ipl_mailer.confirm_doctor_form_submitted_complete.thank_you')
```